Why are some functions from QGIS's C++ API not available in the Python API?
I am working on a Python plugin for QGIS and want to create a new 3D map view with some specific settings. What I want to do is basically this:
canvas = Qgs3DMapCanvas()
map_settings = Qgs3DMapSettings()
map_settings.setLayers([my_raster_layer])
canvas.setMapSettings()

This should be possible (see https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgs3DMapCanvas.html#a7c091e135f6a56a5aa8d623dde30da6c), but somehow the setter for the map settings (along with a few other functions that are available in the C++ API) is not exposed in the Python API, even in the newest QGIS version (see https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.38/_3d/Qgs3DMapCanvas.html). The Qgs3DMapCanvas instance is basically unusable, all getters just return None and using the inherited show function just results in a window with blue background (probably the default behavior for QWindow instances).
Creating a 3D map view by calling iface.createNewMapCanvas3D() results in inconsistent behavior if the user interacts with the layers of the project (I'm not even sure if it's possible or intended to detach 3D map views from the current project); additionally, the Python API just does not seem to include the whole functionality available in the UI, for example it does not seem to be possible to make the 3D view actually 3D by using the DEM elevation values instead of just flat terrain.
I looked into the provided link with an example for point clouds (lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2024/02/05/new-features-in-qgis-36), but it is just not quite what I'm looking to achieve.
Is it possible to somehow access these C++ functions from my Python plugin?

What QGIS version exactly are you using?

See https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2024/02/05/new-features-in-qgis-36/

I'm using QGIS 3.38. The issue is that the C++ API documentation features several functions that do exactly what I need, but somehow are not accessible via the Python API. For example, I also need the 3D view to use the actual terrain from my DEM instead of just being flat, which is done (at least I think so) in the setTerrainGenerator function that is - agian - apparently only available in the C++ API. I can definitely do what I need in an OpenGL widget, I was just wondering if there was a way around all that.

Please [Edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification.

Have you seen the examples in the "Python API for 3D views" section at https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2024/02/05/new-features-in-qgis-36/ ?
